how to apply open-close principle on hierarchical typescript data types
let's imagine the following types autogenerated: I cannot change them.
type BaseProblem = {

    name?: string;
    description?: string;
}

type SimProblem = BaseProblem & {
    type: "sim";
    simNumber?: string;
}

type CarProblem = BaseProblem & {
    type: "car";
    model?: string;
    plate: string;
}

type AllKeys<T> = T extends unknown ? keyof T : never;
type Id<T> = T extends infer U ? {[K in keyof U]: U[K]} : never;
type _ExclusifyUnion<T, K extends PropertyKey> = T extends unknown
    ? Id<T & Partial<Record<Exclude<K, keyof T>, never>>>
    : never;

declare type ExclusifyUnion<T> = _ExclusifyUnion<T, AllKeys<T>>;

type Problem = ExclusifyUnion<CarProblem | SimProblem>;

it's a kind of hierarchical types definition, like in OOP. type helps type-narrowing it.
Now, let's imagine I need to operate on data having those types:
const createCarProblem = () : CarProblem => {
    return({
        type: "car",
        plate: '123A'
    });
};


const isValidBaseProblemToBeSent = (problem: BaseProblem): boolean => {
    // there could be much more logic here
    return (typeof problem.description === 'string');
};

const isValidCarProblemToBeSent = (problem: CarProblem): boolean => {
    // there could be much more logic here
    return isValidBaseProblemToBeSent(problem) && (typeof problem.plate === 'string' );
};

const isValidSimProblemToBeSent = (problem: SimProblem): boolean => {
    // there could be much more logic here
    return isValidBaseProblemToBeSent(problem) && (typeof problem.simNumber === 'string');
};


const isValidToBeSent = <T extends Problem>(problem: T):boolean => {
    // switch here? OCP violation
    switch (problem.type) {
        case 'car':
          return isValidCarProblemToBeSent(problem);
          case 'sim':
          return isValidSimProblemToBeSent(problem);
    };
}

playground here
which are used on some react compoment. everything works, but isValidToBeSent, and other functions that will come, break the open-close principle: new functions will need to switch, or new types will make the rest of the functions to be modified. I was wondering if there's a way to be more OCP without adding functions to the data itself. I would like to be more functional possible, and avoid OOP, since those data and functions will be used within react components

• Please [edit] the code to be a [mre] without typos (bool, Problem, missing type) or pseudocode (...) so we can play around with it and not be distracted by stuff unrelated to the question. It would also help if you'd put some toy "logics" impl in there so we can refactor it and it would be obviously the same or different. • Seems like isValidToBeSent() should be a method of BaseProblem so that any object of that type knows how to validate itself.  But saying you don't want "OOP" seems to contradict that; can you demonstrate how that fails to meet your use case?

edited. am I maybe reasoning way too much OOP-alike for data modelling, when it comes to functional programming? maybe that's the key point. how could I get the same, in a functional way?

• Not sure why you're going through the trouble to exclusify that union since it's already a discriminated union. Can't you just make it type Problem = CarProblem | SimProblem?

• TS doesn't have type classes so you can't make this "functional" without keeping track of the list of possible Problem types in two places. There's nothing wrong with that, but I don't know how to connect that with the open-closed principle. Either I'd do it OOP with methods like this or even better with classes like this... OR you do it functionally like this. I could write either up as an answer, if any of it meets your needs.
